# Protractor, is there a way to use params to configure report directory?

Tags: protractor

I`m using protractor for my e2e tests.
What I have in mind: I want to be able run different suites using one config file and store reports in different directories. When I run from **cmd protractor test.js --params.suite=Name1** it would store reports in folder Name1, when I run **--params.suite=Name2*, it would store reports in Name2 folder.
I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine2-protractor-utils#htmlreportdir

```
var configuration = new function() {
this.reportPath = "C:/xxx/ProtractorTests/";
this.reportFileName = "reportName.html";
this.screenshotPath = "C:/xxx/Screenshots/"; };

exports.config = {

...

params: {
    suite: "SuiteName"
},

plugins: [
    {
        path: 'node_modules/jasmine2-protractor-utils',
        disableHTMLReport: false,
        disableScreenshot: false,
        screenshotPath: configuration.screenshotPath,
        screenshotOnExpectFailure: true,
        screenshotOnSpecFailure: true,
        clearFoldersBeforeTest: true,
        htmlReportDir: configuration.reportPath,
        failTestOnErrorLog: {
            failTestOnErrorLogLevel: 900
        }
    }
],
```

In code above I take paths from configuration function and use it. Can I use **exports.config.params.suite** variable to concatenate report path string? Or am I doing it all wrong and should do it completely differently?
  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [yargs](http://yargs.js.org/) to get the command line arguments:

```
configuration.screenshotPath += '/' + require('yargs').argv.suite
```

Just `npm install yargs --save` to get yargs.